# React-Redux connecting two separate component with a toggle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I know this is probably a very basic question, but it's more of a "I don't understand the docs please help me" type of question.

I'm trying to connect two components using React-Redux: the first is a sidebar, and the second is a modal that should appear when clicking on a button in the sidebar. The components are not related in any parent-child relation (except root) so I assume redux is the best option.

I've read all the redux (and react-redux) docs and I understand the core concepts of redux, but I'm having trouble understanding how to implement them in my components.

Basically I want a button in the sidebar that toggles a stored state (true/false is enough) and according to that state the modal would appears (`state==true => display:block`) and disappear via a button in the modal (`state==false => display:none`).

What I think I need is an action to toggle a state, for example:

```
const modalsSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'modals',
    initalState,
    reducers: {
        toggleModal(state, action){
            state = !state;
        }
    }
});
```

then connecting the action in both components (I'm writing the components in classes not as functions) by using:

```
const toggleModal = {type: 'modals/toggleModal', payload: ''};
const mapStateToProps = state => state.showHideModal;

export default connect(mapStateToProps, toggleModal)(Component);
```

Now, assuming I'm correct so far, I'm not sure how to continue. I.e. how am I suppose to receive and make the change in the components themselves? Sure, I need to put a function in a button with a `onClick={foo}` listener but how does the `foo` suppose to receive and handle the state? And am I suppose to initialize the `showHideModal` state somewhere? In the root component? While configuring the store?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### State Initialisation

You are supposed to initialise the state `showHideModal` in the slice itself. Moreover, it should be named as either `showModal` or `hideModal` for a better interpretation of what this state does.

```
const modalSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'modal',
    initialState: {
      showModal: false,
    },
    reducers: {
      toggleModal(state){
          state.showModal = !state.showModal;
      }
    }
});

export const { toggleModal } = modalSlice.actions;
```

#### SideBar Component

The `onClick` event handler needs to be passed **explicitly** via mapDispatchToProps.

```
import { toggleModal } from './modalSlice';

class Sidebar extends Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    const { toggleModal } = this.props;
    toggleModal();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {/* rest of JSX */}
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Toggle Modal</button>
        {/* rest of JSX */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  toggleModal,
};

export default connect({}, mapDispatchToProps)(Sidebar);
```

#### Modal

**Note:** You cannot access property directly from state like you did `state.showHideModal;`. You need to access the slice first, followed by property present in it `state.modal.showHideModal;`.

```
class Modal extends Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    const { toggleModal } = this.props;
    toggleModal();
  }

  render() {
    const { showModal } = this.props;

    return (
      <>
        {showModal ? (
          <div>
            <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Close</button>
          </div>
        ) : null}
      </>
    );
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  toggleModal,
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  showModal: state.modal.showModal,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Modal);
```

#### Update

Coming, to the the reason why Redux throws following warning:

> A non-serializable value was detected in an action, in the path: `payload`

It's because a [SyntheticEvent](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html) is being passed as a payload to the action. In order to fix this, you need to move the `toggleModal` call from the `onClick prop` to a separate handler function. For you reference, check the `handleClick` function in **Modal** and **SideBar**.

Comment: First, you don't need to define a `{ type, payload }` object as Redux Toolkit handles it internally with `toggleModal` action, which makes `mapDispatchToProps` no different at all. Second, I have **updated the answer with the Modal.js**. Third, that's now how ES6 destructuring assignment works, please read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Comment: Absolutely! You **don't need to** pass `showModal` from the App to Modal as it's being handled by Redux. Just **wrap** the App with a `<Provider />` with **store** as props and you're good to go. Yes, the **order of destructuring** doesn’t matter, either you write `const { foo, bar } = this.props;` or `const { bar, foo } = this.props;`, it stays the same :)

Comment: Nope, still nothing.

Comment: Ok so I added an if statement with `alert` in it in the reducer to see if the state actually changes (you can see in the sandbox) - the state does indeed change! Meaning the reducer works, but something in the `Modal.js` code isn't working.

Comment: Currently the only way I was able to make it work is to add `<Modal>` in the `Sidebar` render function. But this seems like I'm misusing Redux (or at least not utilizing it to its full potential), because the way I understand it if I'm putting `<Modal>` inside `Sidebar` there's no real advantage to using the `store`, I can do it with regular React.

Comment: Please don't use vague phrases such as **sometimes in the code isn’t working** and share the specifies. The code is working either I keep Modal inside Sidebar or App.

Comment: If I knew what wasn't working I could've try to solve it :) Anyway please respond to my last comment: I was managed to get it to work but I need to include `<Modal>` in `<Sidebar>`. Isn't the benefit of using Redux in this scenario is to be able to *not* include `<Modal>`? Otherwise I can just use a parent-child regular React relation.

Comment: Yes, you are not taking advantage of Redux if you're including `Modal` in `Sidebar`. Preferably these components should be **decoupled** and not nested in each other as they serve different functionalities with no correlation. Moreover, you should use [Portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) for developing Modals.

Comment: I don't see how using portals solves this. In the examples I find the Modal component is still being included in the parent component (for example [this tutorial](https://imranhsayed.medium.com/create-modal-in-react-using-portal-48b3662a28b9)). The sole reason for which I tried using Redux here is to avoid this nesting.

Comment: Using portal won't solve this, it's just a better way of writing modals. If you want an answer on where you should keep Modal, please post a new question.

Comment: Well, it's part of this question but I have no problem opening a new one if you think it's necessary. Posted it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65810764).