# Building a Modal component in React without nesting it inside caller component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, modal-dialog

I'm trying to call a Modal from non-related component (without using any parent-child relationship).

In order to do that I'm trying to use React Redux (as the only way I've seen that can make a connection between two unrelated components). An [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-smoke-pdw5d) on CodeSandbox shows the bare minimum of what I'm trying to do.

My issue is that I don't want to include `<Modal>` inside the `<Button>` render function. I want to be able to simply flip the flag in `Button.js` and `<Modal>` would appear. This is, from what I understand, is suppose to be one of the advantages of Redux.

It may be look unimportant, but besides the fact that I understand that this is something that can be done and so I want to know how, it will be useful for me in a different piece of code in which if I include `<Modal>` in the component's render function it'll render the Modal multiple times (I render that component in a list).

Edit:

Just to be clear (as per the example on CodeSandbox), I'm using React classes and not functional components; so no hooks like `useDispatch` but rather functions like `mapDispatchToProps` are the way I want to go here.

Comment: If your button, triggering the modal and the modal itself have common parent and they scattered apart from each other not farther than that, you may avoid using Redux for that sole purpose.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov nope, that's why I emphasized: they have no relation (perhaps other than `App` component, if I'd include `<Modal>` there). The example on CodeSandbox simplifies my actual case, don't take it as simply having some siblings relation.

Answer (score 0):

I will Recommend using React Portal, this will inject it inside the given node, I found it to be the best solution for creating modals. I used same in dailylivedeals.com as a POC

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

render() { 
    return ReactDOM.createPortal(
    this.props.children,
    Document.body
  );
}
```

This is the simplest and cleanest using React's own feature.

Advantage:

1. Cleaner and simpler
2. Each modal instance can have its own modal
3. Multiple modals can be opened ( even from inside a modal)
4. Modal target can be dynamic (like modal inside modal)
5. Multiple modal can be controlled using code easily.

Update :

Eloborate code for modal

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

import "./modal.scss";

let Modal = ({visible, id, hideModal, children, ...props}) => {

    let [show, setShow] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        setShow(visible);
        console.log(visible);
    }, [visible]);

    let toggleVisibility = () => {
        //hideModal();
        setShow(!show);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!show) {
            hideModal();
        }
    }, [show]);


    return <div className="modal-scratchpad">
        {show ?
            ReactDOM.createPortal(
                <div id={`${id}-modal-wrapper`} className="sample-modal-wrapper">
                    <div id={`${id}-modal-backdrop`} className="sample-modal-backdrop">
                    </div>
                    <div id={`${id}-modal-container`} className="sample-modal-container">
                        <div id={`${id}-modal`} className="sample-modal">
                            {children}
                            <div onClick={toggleVisibility} className="sample-modal-cross-button">{'\u2716'}</div>
                        </div>
                        <style type="text/css">
                            {"body {" +
                            "overflow:hidden" +
                            "}"}
                        </style>
                    </div>
                </div>
                , document.body)
            : <></>
        }
    </div>

};

export default Modal;
```

Comment: `createPortal`will not render a new `Modal` component each time the `Button` component is rendered, right? This might be what I need. But from the examples I found Portals still require nesting the `<Modal>` inside the caller component (for example [this tutorial](https://imranhsayed.medium.com/create-modal-in-react-using-portal-48b3662a28b9)). Is there a workaround?

Comment: Yes but in the final render your button wont be having modal as will be transferred to "body", inspect the https://dailylivedeals.com and see yourself, I implemented modals same way for multiple big projects

Comment: Also just to clean up code more, react accepts <></> blank tags too in case you want to get rid of any residue and wrap everything related to modal inside portal

Comment: I guess, with React portals you're somewhat abusing the tool. It's purpose is rather to inject React-powered app into some DOM-node, other than conventional root-div.

Comment: Can I use `createPortal` with a component as parameter? i.e. in my case something like `createPortal(Modal, nodeName)`?

Comment: Or do I need to put `createPortal` in the render function of `Modal`? Because that way I still call `<Modal>` in `<Button>`..

Comment: Not necessarily, it gives you an option to inject an react dom node anywhere in the dom, basic purpose for creating it was to detach node hierarchy of virtual dom vs dom and create a performance efficient code so people who want to manipulate/transfer node manually and them abusing  forceUpdate()/shouldComponentUpdate() of react, surprisingly it really fits the requirement for Modals

Comment: Any approach will work, really depends on the level of control you desire, I will recommend 2nd method, also you dont need to put modal inside button, you can out it beside button and give a parameter to render or hide, check my updated answer

Comment: in the updated code you can use blank tags in place of modal-scratchpad class tag to remove any residue, make sure to provide the required props

Comment: preparing a sandbox for your ease

Comment: I see, and now you need to set the 'show' state from the Button component. Best usage here would be Redux right? If I don't want to insert `<Modal>` in Button.

Comment: Check this https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-microservice-8tf0v?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Yes, modal parent will have control of modal and you modal will inform his parent before closing and will get prop update from parent to close, it can be refined more and css animations can be easily added

Comment: @YechiamWeiss : I strongly recommend you to inquiry about [React Portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html#usage) to get yourself convinced that it is **absolutely not** an appropriate tool to solve your problem

Comment: Thanks @YevgenGorbunkov  I have explored options for months and consulted multiple experts regarding same before implementing it within a library, still I will explore more and will recommend you to do same and communicate if you find any better solution

Comment: @VikasSaini: appealing to some (non-existent, but surely much respected) experts doesn't change the fact that official tutorial clearly describes the use-case for React Portals and above doesn't match that, whatsoever. I won't inquiry any (imaginary) experts on this particular topic since I'm pretty much confident in its proper implementation (spoiler: no Portals involved).

Comment: @VikasSaini: Furthermore, your solution makes even less sense if you think of it: your modal visibility depends on the App state variable (which you toggle with the button click), so you may simply skip that entire Portal thing and conditionally render `<Modal />` component, based on whether that variable is set or not. So your solution violates both of critical OP requirements: 1. It won't work for scattered components; 2. Those are function (rather than class-based) components. Cheers.

Comment: Cool don't use my solutions, you won't be able to digest it anyways ..... your solutions looks good but I will pass on it, please share if you find anything different, I am open to suggestions even if it is form a random guy from internet who is .....

Comment: @VikasSaini : I didn't yet start anything to stop, the assumption about imaginary expert was the only reasonable explanation someone might seriously suggest to do stuff, like that.

Comment: @VikasSaini: magic is the way of explaining something, one is not capable to comprehend, so don't fallback for that track, pay a bit more effort to evolve your knowledge of basic React concepts. I would recommend to start from [Lift State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) it may give you some clues on how you could make your own solution cleaner.